# Regex to parse decimal number with both comma and E/e

Tags: regex

I am trying to write regex so that it returns me true for all the below possibilities

```
1.2E3
12.22e32
+1.2
1,222
3,222
+3,222E23
3.2E2,333
```

A number is valid with comma if after comma I have 3 digits.
I have the regex which returns probably works well for E/e and decimal point

```
[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?
```

I also have below regex which will work well for commas.

```
^(\d?\d?\d(,\d\d\d)*|\d+)(\.\d\d)?$
```

First thing for above regex , I do not understand how it works. I know ^ is used to negate an expression. I understand the rest of the part but why it has to negate it?

I have made a few tries to combine the 2 to get my job done. 
Here are my tries(they do not work for commas)

```
"[-+]?[0-9]*(,[0-9][0-9][0-9])*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?"

"/[1-9](?:\\d{0,2})(?:,\\d{3})*(?:\\.\\d*[1-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)?|0?\\.\\d*[1-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?|0/"
```

Can somebody help me out with this. This seems to be giving me headache

Comment: The ^ in this case is NOT negation. It is anchoring the start of the string.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse decimal numbers? Is this an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

Comment: @btoueg This is not an XY problem. My problem requires me to use regular expression only. I do not have those numbers with me that I can parse, rather I have this regex in my mapping that is to be run my the engine.

Comment: @Akhtar - did any of the answers solve your issue? if so, it's good practice to tick it. This helps future visitors and is good for the answerer.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
/^[+-]?[\d]{1,3}((\.[\d]{1,3})?|(,[\d]{3})*)([eE][\d]{1,3}(,[\d]{3})*)?$/
```

Mind you, there will be more elegant regex for this.

Cheers.

Comment: Using OR definitely won't work when we have both E and commas.

Comment: I tried ^([-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)$|^([-+]?\d?\d?\d(,\d\d\d)*|\d+)(\.\d\d)?$ by combing the two. To my surprise it fails to recognize simple 1.2E, 12.22E32 as valid decimal numbers when the original regex was able to do so.

Comment: hey buddy. if the regex above worked for you you ought to tick the answer. this helps future visitors see what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are not allowing numbers without commas. That is 123456 is not valid unless it's written as 123,456. Given that assumption, this regex will work:

```
^[+-]?\d{1,3}((\.\d{1,3})?|(,\d{3})*)([eE]\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*)?$
```

You can see the details of how it works on [debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%5E%5B%2b-%5D?%5Cd%7B1,3%7D%28%28%5C.%5Cd%7B1,3%7D%29?%7C%28,%5Cd%7B3%7D%29%2a%29%28%5BeE%5D%5Cd%7B1,3%7D%28,%5Cd%7B3%7D%29%2a%29?%24&flags=m&str=1.2E3%0A12.22e32%0A%2b1.2%0A1,222%0A3,222,312%0A%2b3,222,123E23,312%0A3.2E2,333).